# Running DevicePicker class in Kiosk UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, kiosk-mode, posprinter

currently im developing a UWP Kiosk app. This app needs to print to a PosPrinter (EPSON TM-T20II) which is connected via ehternet to the network, The app runs in another pc connected with wifi to the same network. I have created the app using a DevicePicker class just like this example from Microsoft

[PosPrinter c# configuration sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter/cs)

in this example you open a poppup window that lists all your connected devices and filters the Printer. You can choose it and you will have a connection to that printer. The problem is when im using the app in Kiosk Mode in Windows 10 this windows with all the connected printers will not show up, and then i cannot stablish any connection. I have look into the set-multiple-kios apps option for windows 10, but i dont know how to stablish a path to the class known as DevicePicker to allow his functionality with my Kiosk app.

[DevicePickerClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicepicker)

[Multiple-Kiosk-Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps#create-xml-file)

I have also tried to use PosPrinter.GetDefaultAsync() method to get the Printer directly but it always returns null, i also added the deviceCapabillities in my appxmanifest.xml

So if anyone could provideme with a hint or something i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the class FindAllAsync(DeviceClass), this return a collection with all connected devices belonging to that DeviceClass(in my case PosPrinter), after that i just use the Deviceinformation.id to pair the device with my program, like this: `Posprinter.FromIdAsync(String deviceId)`, This way the device picker wont appear, so the Kiosk App will just find the Device and then will pop up a permission asking to Allow the device or not.